# How to do perform a task branching in azure pipelines in case of failure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have 3 task below.
What I want to do is when npm1 succeeds it will perform npm2a and skip npm2b.
And when npm1 fails, it will skip npm2a and execute npm2b.

How can this be done in Azure pipelines?
Please don't point me to a tutorial. [image]

Comment: there are other tasks before those tasks?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, Yes. There are tasks before and after those tasks. However, I want to perform a task branching only on the 3 task above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do perform a task branching in azure pipelines in case of failure?

You could add a command-line or inline PowerShell task between `npm1` and `npm2a` to invoke [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)：

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]npm2b"
```

Then we set the condition for this task with `Only when a previous task has failed`：

[image]

And set a variable `testvar` with default value `npm2a`.

Besides, set the condition for the task `npm2a` and `npm2b`:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['testvar'], 'npm2a'))

and(failed(), eq(variables['testvar'], 'npm2b'))
```

Comment: And set a variable testvar with default value npm2ai -> is this an environment variable or an output variable?

Comment: @DexterBoyGenius, Just the pipeline variable in the Variable tab.